# SRL with nlpnet not works with some sentences

Tags: python, nltk

I installed [nlpnet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nlpnet/) and downloaded [data](http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/download/nlpnet-data.zip). But it works only with some sentences. I use Ubuntu 13.04 32bits and Python 2.7.4 with virtualenv.

Here I posted two examples, the first seems to work, the second no:

### Example 1 (Seem to work):

```
python nlpnet-tag.py srl /path/to/nlpnet-data/
This is the first sentence of the paragraph. This is the second sentence of the paragraph.
This is the first sentence of the paragraph .
sentence
    A1: the paragraph
    A0: first
    V: sentence

This is the second sentence of the paragraph .
sentence
    A1: the paragraph
    A0: second
    V: sentence
```

### Example 2 (Not works):

This sentence is taked from [CoNLL-2005 Examples](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~srlconll/examples.html)

```
python nlpnet-tag.py srl /path/to/nlpnet-data/
The $1.4 billion robot spacecraft faces a six-year journey to explore Jupiter and its 16 known moons.
The $ 1.4 billion robot spacecraft faces a six-year journey to explore Jupiter and its 16 known moons .
```

I also tested from python and tokenization works but in the second example calling `arg_structures`, returns an empty list.

I missed something? ...will be appreciated if you can provide a solution even when not use nlpnet.

Thanks

PS: I also [reported this issue](https://github.com/erickrf/nlpnet/issues/3) but want to see if someone help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

erickrf, the author of the package, [answer](https://github.com/erickrf/nlpnet/issues/3#issuecomment-41072412) it:

> the problem here is that the trained models from
>   http://nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/download/nlpnet-data.zip were trained for
>   Portuguese. It won't work in English.
>
> When you get an empty arg_structures list, it means that the network
>   didn't recognize any token as a predicate.